# Views Select Photos from the album to flag for printing

Tags: flags, views

I have created a Content Type Album and added an image field with the value unlimited.

Created a view page which displays all the images added to a node.

Now I want that the user can select / flag the pictures from the album to print. Keep in mind that I am using pager so the results are divided into several pages.

Admin can get the list of the photos which the user has flagged to print.

Please suggest how this can be achieved.

Comment: What have you already tried? Saving in a cookie or saving in a session variable via ajax are two ways that spring to mind.

Comment: There is the great Flag module that would serve here well, but you'd have to have one image per node, which I think is the most common way anyway.